# Const type qualifier when doing pointer things

Tags: c, c99

Let's say I have a local variable `int var;` that I use for retrieving some value by calling another function, like so: `func(..., &var);`.

Then I check the retrieved value for certain things and act accordingly. After variable `var` has received its value, `var` will never change again from that point on.
Would it then make sense to define `var` as *const*? (`int const var;`).

I'm not sure if that's the correct way to use the *const* keyword because the initial value of `var` is something left over from the stack and changes when `func` is called: `func(..., &var);`. So, in some way that contradicts the *const* type qualifier.

The reason that I'm unsure about this is because the effect (or result) of defining variable `var` as *const* (`int const var;`), is the desired behavior for the code that follows within the scope of `var`.
I.e, it should not be allowed to change the value of `var` directly with the use of the assignment operator even though the value of `var` was just changed by some pointer within the `func` function.

**Example**

```
int foo(void)
{
    int const var;

    if (!func(..., &var))
        return 0;

    if (var == x)
        // do some stuff
    else if (var == y)
        // do some other stuff
    else
        // nope

    return var * x + y;
}
```

I wonder if in terms of correctness the *const* type qualifier for defining `var` still applies to that situation.

---

> Regarding correctness, at least with gcc you can pass your const var
>   to the modifying function, but it generates a warning. I would neither
>   recommend nor do it. It does not help rather than confuse the reader.

It seems that I have stumbled down the wrong path by misinterpreting the resulting behavior of MSVC. While having `/Wall` enabled, the only warning that MSVC produced was `const object should be initialized`. Which I didn't think much of because by just initializing `var`, to see what would happen, the result was a clean compilation.

But I think I have some idea of what is happening, at least. If you have a *const* data type, the compiler thinks that you should not write to something that is read-only, even when doing so with the use of pointers. So, the only time that it makes sense for the compiler to see the address of a *const* variable being passed to a function, is when that variable contains anything but a garbage value. Hence the initialization warning.

> If var is used in equality comparisons like in your example, making it
>   const could avoid the if (var = ...) vs. if (var == ...) typo because
>   the compiler would catch that.

In regard to using *const* or not when trying to catch this error; I think it has more to do with having the assurance of the compiler spitting something out based on the ruling defined within the standard, than it has with the compiler producing or not producing a warning if *const* is omitted from the definition of `var`.

Comment: Note that in C, `const` is a misnomer for *read-only*. `const` qualified objects *are* allowed to change (but you cannot assign to them).

Comment: But still, it feels very counter-intuitive to write (may it be with the use of a pointer) to a *read-only* field/variable.

Comment: I am still unsure what it is that you're asking. Can't you state your question as a single sentence, something like: "is this code below ok or not"?

Comment: I added sample code to illustrate what I think you want, hopefully clarifying the question. If it is not correct, edit it and/or your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap another function to do it.

```
int wrapfun() {
    int var;
    func(..., &var);
    return var;
}
int main()
{
    const int var = wrapfun();
}
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand. There is no reason to wrap the function call of `func` within another function because this changes the scope of the `var` variable. If the scope of `var` changes, then the applicability of defining `var` as *const* no longer holds any value/meaning. Also, your answer could be a lot more valuable if it contained an explanation that describes why you prefer to wrap the function call within another function instead of leaving out the *const* type qualifier from the definition of variable `var`.

Comment: If the calling function was `int foo(void)` instead of `int main()`, this would work as desired.  You'd initialize `int const var = wrapfun();` directly in `foo()`, and there'd be no messy coding around the partly constant, partly not constant scope.  I think this is the best solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Eric Postpischil's answer, you might also extract the block where var should be const into a new function with var as a const parameter. Whether this makes sense or not depends on what actually happens in that block and how much other dynamic state there is to take care of. I would go with the more readable solution.

If you declare var as const in some parts of the code, you make sure that nobody later inadvertently introduces changes to the code that change the value of var. You would make your intentions for that variable explicit and it might help the reader understand the code. If var is used in equality comparisons like in your example, making it const could avoid the `if (var = ...)` vs. `if (var == ...)` typo because the compiler would catch that.

Regarding correctness, at least with gcc you *can* pass your const var to the modifying function, but it generates a warning. I would neither recommend nor do it. It does not help rather than confuse the reader.

```
// const.c
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int *var)
{
    *var = 5;
}

void post(const int var)
{
    printf("%d\n", var);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int var;
    func(&var);
    post(var);
    return 0;
}
```

$ gcc const.c

const.c: In function 'main':

const.c:16:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'func' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

```
 func(&var);
      ^
```

const.c:3:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'const int *'

```
 void func(int *var)
      ^~~~
```

So in this case, I would go without the const in `main`, but you could keep it in `post`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I have placed some comments in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it is ugly:

```
int var;
func(..., &var);
{
    const int sneaky = var, var = sneaky;

    // var is const here.
    ...
}
```

This opens a new block, defines `sneaky` to temporarily hold the value of `var`, and then defines a new `var` that hides the old `var`. Since the old `var` is hidden, we cannot initialize the new one with the old one, so we initialize the new `var` with the value we stashed in `sneaky`.